# Group By or summarize and count

Tags: r

I have raw data as below which enumerators entered same value multiple times I want to summarize it as desired output please refer to attach If you could possibly tell me the code R I will be much appreciate 
Thank you in advance[image: Raw data and desired output]

Comment: Or it is also `df1 %>% filter(!is.na(village_other)) %>% count(enumertor_id, village_other) %>% mutate(Question_name = 'village_other')`

Comment: @akrun what if I check multiple question name as in here it is only village_other what if ethnic groups and iset and all of these should come under one table Thank you Arkun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to do this on all the questions, one option is to reshape to 'long' format and get the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- df1 %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = province:village_other, 
           names_to = "Question_name", values_to= "Text_answer", 
                  values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
     count(enumerator_id, Question_name, Text_answer)

out %>%
   filter(Question_name == 'village_other')
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  enumerator_id Question_name Text_answer     n
#          <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <int>
#1             1 village_other Z               3
#2             2 village_other D               2
#3             3 village_other J               1
```

If we need to have separate columns

```
out %>% 
       pivot_wider(names_from = Question_name, values_from = n)
```

---

Another option is to use `map` to loop over the column names of interest and get the `count` in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
map(names(df1)[3:6], ~ df1 %>% 
                    filter_at(vars(.x), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
                    count(enumerator_id, !! rlang::sym(.x)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(enumerator_id = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1), 
 date = c("5/18/2020", 
"5/19/2020", "5/20/2020", "5/21/2020", "5/22/2020", "5/23/2020", 
"5/24/2020", "5/25/2020"), province = c("A", "C", "X", "E", "A", 
"C", "H", "A"), district = c("B", "A", "Y", "F", "B", "A", "I", 
"B"), village = c("C", NA, NA, "G", NA, NA, NA, NA), village_other = c(NA, 
"D", "Z", NA, "D", "Z", "J", "Z")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: @arkun by question name what I mean is,they are in different columns not same column like village other is a column name and iset is a column name ethnic group is a column name but the output should list all those columns like summarize in question names there should be village_other, iset and some other column names

Comment: @MaxMiak It is much better to reshape into long and then do this at once

Comment: @arkun thank you but still you are filtering only village other I want all those specific variables not only one

Comment: @MaxMiak It was just to show the desired output.  If you check `out` by typing out on console or `View`, the whole output will be present.  Suppose, if the output is 1 million rows, I cannot show the whole number of rows here.  So, i used `filter`, which a good optioni to filter or keep the rows to show the user a snapshot of the rows

Comment: @arkun THANK YOU so much for answers and patient one last question can I concatenate specific variables in cols like cols=c(village_other,A,B) in order to get only those columns?

Comment: @MaxMiak `cols=c(village_other,A,B)` is enough in `pivot_longer`

Comment: @MaxMiak I would do a `select` before i.e. `df1  %>% select(enumerator_id, village_other,A,B) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -enumerator_id,  names_to = "Question_name", values_to= "Text_answer", 
                  values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% count(enumerator_id, Question_name, Text_answer)` to remove unwanted columns

Comment: @arkun Thank you but it will give me suppose B in Question_name columns as an output but I want all selected variables

Comment: i also posted anotherv solution

Comment: @arkun even while concatenating cols=c(A,B,C) it gives only one column name in Question names for example only C in question_names

Comment: i posted solution with map